# How can I increase volume for HD mp4 files with ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-streaming, sox

I am converting videos using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) on Linux.
Videos are 1080p at first and I convert 1080p to h264 720p and 360p. Also if videos are 360p I`m converting them to h264 360p.
The problem is when converting happens from 1080p to lower formats the sound is really really quiet while 360p to h264 360p are fine and you can hear them without problems on laptop.

I thought [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) might be useful for this, but I was only able to make it work with .wav audio files and not the .mp4 videos that I need.

I could do it `ffmpeg -vol` option, but there could be noise, while I read that SoX calculates the maximum value so there would not be any side effects.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the ffmpeg command and its result, to help you?

Comment: If you can just copy the audio data (`-acodec copy`) then there should be no difference between input and output audio, unless you have audio level metadata that you are not copying (EBU R128 or ReplayGain).

Comment: The problem is in the input files.Have you ever downloded a HD movie? They are almost always much much quiter then standard quality.

Comment: The [SoX website says](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features) it works with MPEG (.mp4) using FFmpeg.

Comment: See also [decrease volume of existing audio stream in a video ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/q/982398) and [Increase mean volume of a video/audio file](https://superuser.com/q/942230)