# decrease volume of existing audio stream in a video ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to add new audio to a video at a particular point in a video (which has its own audio stream). I used the first answer in this question to achieve it: [ffmpeg placing audio at specific location](https://superuser.com/questions/716320/ffmpeg-placing-audio-at-specific-location-with-complex-filters)

However, I am now trying to reduce the volume of the existing audio on the video so that the original audio isn't as prominent in the output file. Is there any way to do this (with ffmpeg) using the same command shown in the answer of the question I have linked?

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off extracting the entire audio stream from the video as a WAV or MP3 -> open it in, say, Audacity -> use said audio editor to manipulate the volume/normalize the audio -> use FFMPEG to re-add the audio track...

Comment: Is there any way of doing the same thing with ffmpeg?

Comment: It's fairly complicated and may not give you best results: http://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Just managed to figure it out. Had to add in a simple aeval filter. More here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aeval

Comment: Stick it up as an answer and you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, you can add an aeval filter to the command that I have linked in the OP to manipulate the original audio stream. More here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aeval

Comment: Showing your complete command will be helpful for others wanting to do the same thing.